# Некорректное сравнение времён в базах данных sqlite3. Работа с unixtime в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Всем привет! В моей базе данных есть поле с названием unixtime в котором хранится дата(именно дата в формате: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS).Так вот, я бы хотел вывести записи, которые были произведены за последний час, но используя синтаксис работы с unixtime(т.е. я пытаюсь сравнить datetime с unixtime). Подскажите, корректно ли это? Если да, то почему вот такой запрос выдаёт не то, что мне нужно (он выводит старые записи с неправильным врменем за 2002 год в том числе)?

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE datetime(unixtime) > (strftime('%s', 'now') - 3600)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `strptime()`, наверное. У вас сырое значение — строка? Если нет, отредактируйте вопрос с добавлением примера сырого значения. Ну и для профилактики: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time

Comment: `select datetime(unixtime), strftime('%s', 'now') from test;` - выполните этот запрос, посмотрите, что пытаетесь сравнивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Я понял, что не корректно сравнивать `datetime('2019-02-03')` с временем типа unixtime `strftime('%s', 'now')`. Это разные типы времён, сравнивать так НЕЛЬЗЯ.
Для решения моей задачи(работа с unixtime в sqlite) нужно хранить в полях с unixtime строки(text), которые в python можно привести к типу float и полученные числа неотрицательны. Я поменял хранимые значения в поле unixtime и таблица стала выглядеть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я делаю запрос следующего вида, чтобы вывести все записи за последний час, используя unixtime: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE unixtime > (strftime('%s', 'now') - 3600)`.
Если же я просто хочу вывести все записи после какого-то unixtime (1566206652.099592), то нужно добавить параметр 'unixepoch' в функцию strftime: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE unixtime > strftime('%s', '1566206652.099592', 'unixepoch')`